# Пишется undefined

Tags: javascript, html

Пишу простейшую задачу в JAVASCRIT, кажется все правильно написал, но на выходе получаю: количество дней undefined

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title> javascript </title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var days = ["понедельник", "вторник", "среда"];
      var count = days.lenght;
      document.write("количество дней " + count);
    </script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы просто неправильно слово `length` написали )

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title> javascript </title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var days = ["понедельник", "вторник", "среда"];
      var count = days.length;
      document.write("количество дней " + count);
    </script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```